# Validar si una PK está siendo utilizada en otra tabla

Tags: c#, sql

Hola estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con c# y quisiera saber como puedo validar que al eliminar un registro en este caso de la tabla Region, su cod_region que es su PK no esté siendo utilizado por otra tabla, para que en caso de si está siendo utilizado por otra tabla envíe un mensaje de alerta o en caso contrario se elimine el registro. Existen 2 tablas la tabla region que tiene como pk cod_region y la tabla provincia que utiliza cod_region para registrar provincias.

Yo estaba intentado realizar esto de la siguiente manera:

Cree un método que elimina el registro según el cod_región seleccionado en una tabla.

```
    public bool DeleteEliminarREGION(RegionObject request)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = dbproyecto.openConnection();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaccion = conn.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Transaction = transaccion;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<RegionObject> listado = (List<RegionObject>)js.Deserialize(request.regionJson, typeof(List<RegionObject>));
            string query = "";
            bool resultado = true;
    
            try
            {
    
                foreach (RegionObject item in listado)
                {
    
                    query = "";
    
                    query = @"DELETE FROM dev_auto_region
                                WHERE cod_region = @cod_region";
                             
    
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
    
    
    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_region", item.codRegion);
    
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    
    
                    resultado = true;
    
                }
    
                if (resultado)
                {
                    transaccion.Commit();
                }
    
                return resultado;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultado = false;
                transaccion.Rollback();
                string error = ex.Message;
                return resultado;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

y aparte cree otro método que busca en la tabla provincia que es la tabla donde se ocupa el cod_region de la tabla region mediante un select COUNT

```
public bool comprobarEliminacionRegion(RegionObject datos)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = dbproyecto.openConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        bool resultado = false;
        try
        {
            string query = @"SELECT COUNT(1) AS result FROM dev_auto_provincia dap WHERE dap.cod_region = @cod_region";

            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_region", datos.codRegion);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (Int32.Parse(reader["result"].ToString()) > 0)
                {
                    resultado = true;
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            return resultado;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Despues en mi controlador los llamé de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Region_eliminarREGIONcontroller : ApiController
        {
            public object Post(RegionObject request)
            {
                try
                {
                    RegionModel modelo = new RegionModel();
                    Dictionary<string, object> resultado = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    if (modelo.comprobarEliminacionRegion(request))
                    {
                        resultado.Add("error", "Código o nombre de región ya existe, reintente nuevamente");
                        return Ok(resultado);
                    }
                    resultado.Add("resultado", modelo.DeleteEliminarREGION(request));
                    return Ok(resultado);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                    return InternalServerError(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Esto no me ha funcionado y quisiera saber si hay otra manera de realizar esto o si a mi código le falta algo, ojalá me puedan ayudar

Comment: que quiere decir que no te funciono?

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que crees una relación entre las tablas involucradas para que sea el manejador el que mantenga la integridad referencial. El enfoque que le intentas dar no es infalible. En ese instante después de la instrucción `modelo.comprobarEliminacionRegion(...)` y antes de `modelo.DeleteEliminarREGION(...)` puede ser insertado un registro con el `cod_region` que quieres eliminar.